# How to bypass JPA level2 cache for query and find

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jpa-2.0, datanucleus

I'm using JPA2 with level2 cache enabled (jcache/memcache) on GAE. I have to run some update transactions and would like them to rely on datastore data and not the cached one. I tried to set the javax.persistence.cache.retrieveMode property to "BYPASS" when using the JPA find method but it doesn't seem to work at all. So I wonder if cache bypass is possible with datanucleus JPA2 ?

Code sample :

```
if (bypassCache) {
        return find(className, Collections.Collections.<String,Object>singletonMap("javax.persistence.cache.retrieveMode",CacheRetrieveMode.BYPASS));
    }
    else return find(className);
```

I'm using datanucleus 3.1.3 and appengine 1.7.7.1.

Thanks !

After reading the source code of datanucleus I understand that the JPA cache bypass is not implemented for now for the find methods. Could anyone confirm ?

In fact it seems that EntityManager.find() methods are always L2 cached whatever the properties you set. I did a JPQL query and the query result isn't L2 cached. (datanucleus.query.results.cached is false by default). So my understanding is I should use Queries to get fine control of L2 cache.